# solve this simple differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Just a small part of what i'm doing right now, I have to solve $d^2 f/ dx^2 =c f$ for a constant $c$ (which may be complex) and a function $f$ which might get complex values. the domain is $[0,1]$.

for some reason I have a total blackout and need a small reminder.

I recall that for positive $c$ we have $exp$ for a solution, for negative we have $Aexp(i*constx)+Bexp(i*const*x)$, etc..
Would it be bad to guess that the general solution for general $c$ is $A*exp(k*x)$ for some complex constants $A,c$?

Comment: it is not a bad guess.  $y' = cy \implies y = A e^{ct}, y'' = cy\implies y = A e^{\sqrt ct}+Be^{-\sqrt ct}$ and if c is negative and real then $\sqrt c$ is "imaginary."  And if $c$ is complex?  what is $\sqrt c$?

Comment: $\sqrt(re^(i*\theta))=\sqrt(r)*e^(i*\theta/2)$ could work?
p.s is taking combinations of plus and minus necessary? i suppose it is (two initial contiditions)

Answer (score 1):

Using Laplace transform:

$$f''(x)=\text{C}f(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_x\left[f''(x)\right]_{(s)}=\mathcal{L}_x\left[\text{C}f(x)\right]_{(s)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_x\left[f''(x)\right]_{(s)}=\text{C}\cdot\mathcal{L}_x\left[f(x)\right]_{(s)}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use:

- $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[f(x)\right]_{(s)}=\text{F}(s)$$
- $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[f''(x)\right]_{(s)}=s^2\text{F}(s)-sf(0)-f'(0)$$

  ---

$$s^2\text{F}(s)-sf(0)-f'(0)=\text{C}\text{F}(s)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$s^2\text{F}(s)-\text{C}\text{F}(s)=sf(0)+f'(0)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{F}(s)\left[s^2-\text{C}\right]=sf(0)+f'(0)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{F}(s)=\frac{sf(0)+f'(0)}{s^2-\text{C}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\text{F}(s)\right]_{(x)}=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{sf(0)+f'(0)}{s^2-\text{C}}\right]_{(x)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$f(x)=f(0)\cosh\left(x\text{C}\right)+\frac{f'(0)\sinh\left(x\text{C}\right)}{\sqrt{\text{C}}}$$